# Ubuntu phone on galaxy s3

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

Can I install Ubuntu touch on my phone?

My phone is galaxy s3.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said. No.
Have a look at this site https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices.
Currently the only supported devices are:

- Galaxy Nexus
- Nexus 4
- Nexus 7
- Nexus 10

Comment: Notice that scrolling down the page there's a list of unofficial images. In particular, for the [Samsung Galaxy S3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9300) (the one the OP is talking about)...